# Event store and optimistic concurrency

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, optimistic-concurrency, eventstoredb

Greg Young in his document on CQRS in the ["Building an event storage"](https://github.com/keyvanakbary/cqrs-documents) section, when writing events to the event store he checked for optimistic concurrency. I do not really get why he made that check, can anyone explain to me with a concrete example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I do not really get why he made that check, can anyone explain to me with a concrete example.

Event stores are supposed to be persistent, in the sense that once you write an event, it will be visible to every subsequent read.  So every action in the database should be an append.  A useful mental model is to think of a singly linked list.

If a database is going to support more than one thread of execution having write access, then you are faced with the "lost update" problem.  Drawn as linked lists, this might look like:

```
Thread(1) [... <- 69726c3e <- /x.tail] = get(/x)
Thread(2) [... <- 69726c3e <- /x.tail] = get(/x)
Thread(1) set(/x, [ ... <- 69726c3e <- 709726c3 <- /x.tail])
Thread(2) set(/x, [ ... <- 69726c3e <- 83b97195 <- /x.tail])
```

The history written by thread(2) doesn't include event:709726c3 recorded by thread(1).  Thus "lost update".

In a generic database, you typically manage this with transactions: some magic under the covers keeps track of all of your data dependencies, and if the preconditions don't hold when you try to commit your transaction, all of your work is rejected.

But event stores don't use need all of the degrees of freedom that support the general case -- edits to events stored in the database are forbidden, as is changing the dependencies between events.

The only mutable part of the change - which is the only place where we replace overwrite an old value with a new value - is when we change `/x.tail`

```
Thread(1) [... <- 69726c3e <- /x.tail] = get(/x)
Thread(2) [... <- 69726c3e <- /x.tail] = get(/x)
Thread(1) set(/x, [ ... <- 69726c3e <- 709726c3 <- /x.tail])
Thread(2) set(/x, [ ... <- 69726c3e <- 83b97195 <- /x.tail])
```

The problem here is simply that Thread(2) thought `6 <- /x.tail` was true, and replaced it with a value that lost event 7.  If we change our write from a `set` to a `compare-and-set`...

```
Thread(1) [... <- 69726c3e <- /x.tail] = get(/x)
Thread(2) [... <- 69726c3e <- /x.tail] = get(/x)
Thread(1) compare-and-set(/x, 69726c3e <- /x.tail, [ ... <- 69726c3e <- 709726c3 <- /x.tail])
Thread(2) compare-and-set(/x, 69726c3e <- /x.tail, [ ... <- 69726c3e <- 83b97195 <- /x.tail]) // FAILS
```

then the data store can detect the conflict and reject the invalid write.

Of course, if the data store sees the actions of the threads in a different order, then
the command that fails could change

```
Thread(1) [... <- 69726c3e <- /x.tail] = get(/x)
Thread(2) [... <- 69726c3e <- /x.tail] = get(/x)
Thread(2) compare-and-set(/x, 69726c3e <- /x.tail, [ ... <- 69726c3e <- 83b97195 <- /x.tail])
Thread(1) compare-and-set(/x, 69726c3e <- /x.tail, [ ... <- 69726c3e <- 709726c3 <- /x.tail]) // FAILS
```

Put more simply, where `set` gives us "last writer wins" semantics, `compare-and-set` gives us "first writer wins", which eliminates the lost update concern.

Comment: If I have multiple event producers that depends on previous events to produce new events, they all should keep track of the last version of the event stream in order to take correct decision.

Answer (score 4):

TLDR; This concurrency check is needed because what events are emitted depends on the previous events. So, if there are other events that are emitted concurrently by another process then the decision must be re-made.

The way that an Event store is used is like this:

1. The old events are loaded from the Eventstream (=a partition in the Eventstore that contains all the events that were generated by an Aggregate instance)
2. The old events are processed/applied by the Aggregate that owns them in the order they were generated
3. The Aggregate, based on the internal state that was build from those events, decides to emit some new events
4. These new events are appended to the Eventstream

So, step 3 depends on the previous events that were generated before this command is executed.

If some events generated in parallel by another process are appended to the same Eventstream then it means that the decision that was made was based on a false premise and thus must be re-taken by repeating from step 1.

Comment: Events are emitted as a reaction to commands !, my understanding goes like this: Commands are coming in, Aggregate process them depending on its current state and the business logic if OK send some events, events are stored in the event store with the aggregate ID, if we have one instance by aggregate ID, I don't see the need to check for concurrency problem.

Comment: `Events are emitted as a reaction to commands ` - of course, I already wrote: `So, step 3 depends on the previous events that were generated before this command is executed`

Comment: `if we have one instance by aggregate ID, I don't see the need to check for concurrency problem` - you could easily have a situation in which the same Aggregate instance processes more commands *at the same time*

Comment: If I understand you right, you're saying that after the aggregate has loaded its state from the store and are engaging to process a new command other events that it depend on them for processing the command are written to the store, so he need to reload his state the process the command.

Comment: thank you I see it crystal clear now, but is there any chance that we will reload events many times if we are on a very busy system ? is this a limitation of event sourcing or of the implementation of the event store ?.

Comment: @Houss_gc yes, there is that chance, however I never heard anyone complaining.  You can use snapshoting but only if you *really* need.